# C++ Set Iterator in Class

Tags: c++, iterator, segmentation-fault

I have a class, which has a member named _Emails. It is of the type `set<PEmail*>`. When I'm in a member function, and run the following code, it works as expected:

```
for( set<PEmail*>::iterator it=this->_Emails->begin(); it!=this->_Emails->end(); ++it )
  { 
    cout << "Email: " << (*it)->getEmail() << endl;
  }
```

That is, it yields a list of email addresses. Now, I'd like to be able to add to this set as the class grows, and not lose my place of last iteration. I attempted to make another member of my class, named _EmailItr, of type `set<PEmail*>::iterator`. I initialize it in my constructor, right after my _Emails, like so:

```
this->_Emails = new set<PEmail*>;
this->_EmailItr = this->_Emails->begin();
```

Then, attempting to do a similar for loop:

```
// send the max queue amount, or until there are no more emails                                         
for( int i=0;  i<this->_QueueSize || i==_Emails->size(); ++i )
  {
    cout << "i: " << i << endl;
    cout << "QueueSize: " << this->_QueueSize << endl;
    cout << "Emails: " << this->_Emails->size() << endl;

    cout << (*_EmailItr)->getEmail() << endl;
  }
```

I get the following output:

```
i: 0
QueueSize: 2
Emails: 2
Segmentation fault
```

What gives? Am I trying to use iterators in an improper way?

Comment: Identifiers that begin with an underscore and a capital letter are reserved for the implementation for all purposes.  I'd suggest changing those identifiers and getting out of the underscore-capital habit before you get a really weird error.

Comment: As a side note if you want to use an ordered container (i.e. `std::set`, `set:map` & their multi counterparts) for storing pointers to objects (`set<PEmail*>`) and not copies of objects you'll need to provide a strict weak ordering predicate otherwise or you're in for some surprises...

Comment: @David: What do you mean they're reserved? I've never been told that, can you show me? Thanks!

Comment: It's section 17.4.3.1.2 of the Standard: Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
— Each name that contains a double underscore _ _ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
— Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you get `this->_Emails->begin()` right after creating the `std::map`, the iterator you get is the end iterator (because there are no elements in the `std::map`, its size is zero and `begin() == end()`).  You cannot dereference or increment an end iterator.  It doesn't point to "the beginning of the container;" it points to "the element currently at the beginning" or if the container is empty, it returns the end iterator.

(On an unrelated note, it looks like you are doing way too much dynamic allocation.  Why are you creating the `std::set` object dynamically (using `new`)?  Why not just have a `std::set` as a member of the class?)

Answer (score 2):

When you first create the set `_Emails`, and then set `_EmailItr` to `_Emails->begin()`, the iterator is not pointing to anything.  In fact, it is pointing to `_Emails->end()`, since when the set is empty, `begin()` and `end()` are the same.

So later, you attempt to dereference an iterator which points to `end()`, which is undefined behavior and leads to your crash.

You seem to be assuming that the iterator is actually somehow "updating" behind the scenes as you add new objects to the list.  It's not.  It's always pointing to `end()`.  You need to set it to `_Emails->begin()` *after* you insert elements into the set.

Also, unrelated to your question, but: is there some reason you need to allocate `_Emails` on the heap?

Answer (score 1):

The STL `set` is well-behaved when inserting new elements during an iteration.  In particular, if you're iterating over a `set` while adding new elements, you won't "lose track" of where you are; your iterator will remain valid and it will see any new elements that were added or removed.  I'm not fully sure what your use case is here, but I don't think you need all of the added machinery you've introduced here.  Just using a good old-fashioned iterator without any adornments should work just fine.

Comment: What I have is a set of email addresses, being queued. When either 100 /more/ have been added to it, or the app is done queueing, I need it to dump either the 100, or what's left into the SMTP queue. So, I need a global iterator, so I can keep track of last queued emails between subsequent calls to the function. And, I can't just dump the set after each for loop, because I need to maintain its state to prevent duplicates.

Comment: @Josh- Out of curiosity, why aren't you using a `std::queue` instead of a `set` here?  Or possibly a `std::deque`?  That seems better-suited to what you're doing than the `std::set`.

Comment: @Josh: `std::set` stores its elements in sorted order, not in insertion order. Are you inserting e-mails into the set in sorted order? If not, I don't think your described scenario will work.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Won't a deque or queue require the elements to be popped off to access? As I said I need to maintain the object's elements throughout the lifecycle of the object. I'm using set because someone suggested that it was faster than a vector, and I figured I could get away without accessing indexes if I used an iterator.

Comment: @James: Oh crap, I forgot about that!

Comment: @Josh, saying `set` is "faster" than `vector` is pretty meaningless.  It's faster than `vector` for certain use-cases, like if you're looking up elements by something other than their index, in which case each lookup is `O(log N)` time.  But if you're looking up by index, `vector` is faster because each lookup is `O(1)` time.  A `set` also keeps elements in sorted order.  So it really depends on your requirements.